# Data Validation from remote call -Microservices

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

I am bit confused, whether I should validate the data returned from the remote call to another Microserivce Or should I rely on the contract between these Microservice.

I know putting extra checks will not hurt anyone but I would like to know what's the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in theory, you don't even know how the data you get back from a microservices is created since you only know the interface (API) and what it is returning. 
By that, you should take the data response of this API as given.

Sure, additional validation may not harm in the first place.

But consider a case where some business-logic got changed which lead to a change in one of the services. Could be a simple thing like adapting the definition of a KPI leading to a different response (datawise, not structurewise) from the microservice.
Your validation would fail too as false-positive. You would need to adapt your validation for basically nothing.